# Update an existing SQL table by the logic: If key exists then update, else append

Tags: python, sql, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have a SQL data table that is updated daily. Previously I used `'if_exists=replace'` in my `to_sql()` function, however this deletes existing data base altogether and creates a new one. With this deletion the previous settings for primary keys are gone as well and this causes problems.

What i want is to update the existing table with the new data contained in the data frame `new_recommendations`. If the table already exists, it will keep the structure and update the records with matching primary keys. If a record with the same primary key already exists, its values will be updated with the values from the `new_recommendations`.

Here is my code:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

# Create a connection to the database
engine = create_engine('mssql+pymssql://username:password@SQLdatabase/Production')

# Write the DataFrame to the database

new_recommendations.to_sql(
    'RECOMMENDATIONS',                                         # set table name
    con=engine,                                                # set engine
    if_exists='replace',                                       # set exists action
    schema='dbo',                                              # set schema
    index=False,                                               # avoid extra columns to be generated
    chunksize=10000,                                           # set the chunk size for batch insert
    dtype={                                                    # specify data types if needed
        'OptionID': sqlalchemy.types.String(length=20),        
        'RecoID': sqlalchemy.types.String(length=20),
        'Similarity': sqlalchemy.types.Float,
        'ProductGroup': sqlalchemy.types.String(length=100)
    }
)
```

Comment: Why closing? The other thread does not answer what I need.